# How to allow import to intelliJ - all imports are unused

Tags: java, intellij-idea, import

I am newbie in programing. I use IntelliJ IDEA v.14.0.
I try to learn some Java basics, but when I enter at the beginning of the `import java.util.*;` it becomes

> Unused import statement

That happens when I add semicolon at the and of the row.
[Unused import statement](http://postimg.org/image/frh7o7dix/)

Instead of just to import `import java.util.*;` I have to write in the [code](http://postimg.org/image/kc1dhvewv/) every time `java.util.Arrays.sort(int_array1);`

I tried many different classes to import, but all they become "Unused import statement"

How can I import classes without this problem?

Comment: would you mind sharing your code? What's empty while rectangles? Where have you used `Arrays.sort` there?

Comment: Sorry for late response, but @yole gave me an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

That warning means you're importing a lot of classes that you don't use.

Personally I never use `*`. I only import the classes I use. If you have too many imports, it's a sign your class is probably doing too much and you might consider refactoring (see [God object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object)).

You can just do like this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
```

Anyway, if you're using IntelliJ (or any IDE), let it handle the imports for you (for IntelliJ: Alt-Enter on the red underlined class -> Import class).

Answer (score 1):

The import statement is unused when you enter it, because you haven't yet entered the code that uses the import. This is correct and you should not worry about it. Once you enter the code that uses the import, it will no longer be highlighted as unused.